# Error when using qualtRics::fetch_survey() with partial

Tags: r, purrr, qualtrics

I'm getting the following error message when using qualtRics::fetch_survey function together with purrr::partial:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(qualtRics)

fetch_new_survey <- partial(fetch_survey, 
                            force_request = TRUE)

fetch_new_survey(some_survey_id)
```

> Error in vapply(match.call(), deparse, "character") : `values must be
>   length 1, but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 68

Am I using partial incorrectly, or is there something else going on here?

Comment: Does a regular fetch_survey(some_survey_id, force_request = TRUE) call work? Can you provide a working example of a survey id so that I can reproduce your example?

Comment: @pgcudahy yes, a regular fetch_survey() call works.  I can't provide a working example b/c you don't work for my organization and have API access to our Qualtrics instance.